# Flash Notice Alert dismiss-able bootstrap and rails -- Cannot Delete flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an emailer with ruby on rails and it has a flash notice on completion.  I cannot seem to delete the bootstrap flash notice when I Press the x button listed next to the flash notice.  I have tried jquery.

Whenever I put the class close on the button. the button does not even show up to even be clicked.  Here is some of my code.
This is my `create.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert-dismissible flash_notice" role="alert">
     <button type="button"  data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">xxx<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is my contact controller that emails me from a contact me form and renders the flash notice

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here is some of my application.js code... it is messy and I have tried all of the following and left them all up to show you what I have done so far in my attempts.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .


$('.delete_notice').click(function() {

   $('.alert-dismissible').hide();
});

$('.delete_notice').click(function() {

   $('.alert-dismissible').close();
});

$('.delete_notice').click(function() {

   $('.flash_notice').hide();
});

$('.delete_notice').click(function() {

   $('.delete_notice').close();
});
```

Comment: try `$('.delete_notice').on('click', function(){
   $('.alert-dismissible').hide();
});`

Comment: put your js code inside `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () { // Your code here });`, or you can try to do like: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () { $('.alert-dismissible').fadeOut(3000); });`